# Access(read-only) Windows registry from a web-page?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, registry

Barring a custom browser-plugin, is there a way to read the Windows registry from a web-page? It sounds like a big security issue but the situation is we have very non-savvy users and we want to have them get some info about their machines for us. Even downloading and running a little app might confuse them, but a web-page that magically gets the info would be fine as they just click a link we send.

Any thoughts on how to do this, or if it's simply impossible, are welcome. Note it is corporate therefore Windows-only and can even be IE-only if needed.

Comment: Can't you send them a batch file which would echo the value out for you? Then you just ask them to click on the batch file, and voila. If they have trouble copying and pasting from a cmd window, you can echo it on an HTML page and then open that from the batch file after retrieving the value.

Comment: I didn't know a .bat file could access the registry but no anyway, we don't print the values directly but a processed value based on them.

Comment: You can do your calculations/'processing' in a batch file.

Comment: Also, if it can be IE only, SLaks solution of using ActiveX seems fine.

Comment: @Swati: a pure ActiveX control in a page doesn't have to be 'installed', right - only allowed to run?

Comment: Your users will have to click on "install this plugin" when they visit the page. IE will prompt.

Answer (score 1):

No; you need ActiveX or a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from an ordinary web page.

If it's acceptable to have the user download a file, you can write an HTA -- a standalone web page with access to certain Windows features, including the file system and registry.